# Crawler/Bot activity triggering deletion of critical website files - what code in Odoo v9 could be causing this deletion to occur due?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

**Context**:

Odoo v9 docker image installed behind NginX reverse proxy, on a publicly facing bare domain (e.g. mydomain.com), website builder installed, not other configuration or apps.

**Problem**:

Periodically a critical file will go missing:

```
2015-10-30 15:28:28,266 1 INFO db-test werkzeug: 172.17.0.25 - - [30/Oct/2015 15:28:28] "GET /web/content/407-17599c5/website.assets_frontend.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
2015-10-30 15:28:28,281 1 INFO db-test openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /var/lib/odoo/filestore/db-test/e6/e69e06808b908fc0d85ebfea58fbc7df3788e72e
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 151, in _file_read
 r = open(full_path,'rb').read().encode('base64')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/lib/odoo/filestore/db-test/e6/e69e06808b908fc0d85ebfea58fbc7df3788e72e'
```

This file is an auto generated, compressed javascript file with all the common js assets for the website to function.  Thus the site and app become unusable.  Restoring the file fixes this problem.  It is unclear if other files are going missing or not.

**So Far**:

- It only happens when the domain is publicly facing and accessible 
  (when firewalled off to only serve me, this does not happen when
  on a different non-indexed (e.g. by Google) domain this does not
  happen.)
- So far this does not happen with robots.txt set to
  "Disallow: /" - it may take a bit longer to prove this is actually
  preventing the issue, but this is a long while for the problem not to
  have happened.
- An initial manual crawl using wget does not trigger
  this issue - though this was tested as a fresh recursive get of
  current content on the domain that this issue occurs

  - I haven't done a recrawl, or requested out of date urls, so may not paint the full picture
- For more lengthy background into the
  investigation of this, see:
  https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/updated-how-do-i-prevent-website-common-asset-files-from-constantly-not-being-found-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-92982
- Is this oddly due to the domain name being domain.tld rather than
  www.domain.tld?
- or is this a quirk of a bot/crawler that is triggering something it
  shouldn't?
- or is this a bug that doesn't handle requests for old/expired or
  unknown urls well?
- or a combination of the above?
- or maybe even malicious activity?

At this point, it looks like it could be a very concerning security issue, that an external, anonymous (not logged in) user can trigger a catastrophic file deletion inside the odoo software.  Given all the variables tested so far, this very much looks like the source of the issue.  If it is, it would be a significant security flaw.   Has anyone else upgraded to v9 experienced this problem?  It is likely only going to happen to sites that are already established and indexed by Google etc.

Any help to properly identify and solve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone still needs to solve this, there was a bug in the odoo code that was fixed in a later release.  Info here:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/9495

Answer (score 0):

Because of some reason this record is deleted(currently not present) from location `/var/lib/odoo/filestore/db-test/e6/` or path of your **data_dir /filestore/database_name**

I had Same Error, so I just delete that record from `**ir_attachment**` table. This is not a proper way but **problem solved**

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of backups, one of them includes the database besides the dump into the .zip file.

This happens to me when I just do a backup & restore using the dump variant.

That way excludes the file store, so one could have ir.attachment records referring to inexistent files in the file store.